# Explicit Equation for Quadratic Funnel Surface

Tags: functions, quadratics, 3d, surfaces

I've been trying to figure out an explicit form for a quadratic funnel surface, but I'm not succeeding. Essentially, I'm wanting an explicit form for the surface that would be created by revolving the following curve around the y-axis:
[image]

This curve has the formula (for $x<1$):
$$y=\sqrt{-\left(x-1\right)^{2}+1}$$

The closest I got was this:

$$y = \max\left(\sqrt{-(|x|-1)^2+1}, \sqrt{-(|z|-1)^2+1} \right)$$

Which gives me:

[image]
But this isn't quite right since it has a hard crease at each corner. What is the correct formula?

Comment: Replace $x$ by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to give $z=\sqrt{-(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)^2+1}$. (So you're measuring distance from the origin)

Comment: @David, perfect, thank you!